# jest running tests appending s to the command

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs, npm-scripts

I want to ask the community if they have ever seen this issue before.

when running a simple "npm t" command, I am getting the following error

```
    GTaylor@slayer MINGW64 /d/slayer/packages/components (feature/HUBBLU-54)
    $ npm t

    > fl-components@1.0.0 test D:\slayer\packages\components
    > jest --config=jest.json

    s" --config=jest.json was unexpected at this time.

    D:\slayer\packages\components>)s" --config=jest.json
    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

the script is

```
    "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -d",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.json"
    }
```

If I run the command directly this work. I also have other project (in another solution) that works.

This is a Lerna project with multiple packages and they all suffer from the same issue. Note that this was working on one point.

I have no idea where the "s" is coming from. It feels like it trying to run a following command .. but where the hell is the "s" and new lines coming from????

```
    "jest --config=jest.json\n\ns -config=jest.json"
```

please help before I go mad.... :)